# Creating local database at run time with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, vs-community-edition

Beginner's question - please can I ask for advice on creating local database files programmatically at run time. I want to be able later to rename, delete them etc using Windows Explorer in the same way as for text and other files, and to copy them to other computers.

This is using Visual Studio Community 15 with C#, installed SQL server Data Tools 14.0.50616.0. The computer has Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

For an example I have removed the surplus parts of my program to leave the code below, which uses a Windows Form Application with 3 buttons (`btnCreateDb`, `btnDeleteDb`, and `btnDoesDbExist`) and a combobox `cbxDb` for the database name. It makes databases in an existing folder `C:\DbTemp`.

It will apparently create and delete a new database and make files, for example `mydb1.mdf` and `mydb1.ldf` in the folder, and state that they exist. However, if I delete the two files using Explorer, it throws an exception if an attempt is made to delete  or to create the database; and `btnDoesDbExist` shows that it still exists.

Why does the database still appear to exist when the files have been deleted by Windows Explorer? The code under `btnDoesDatabaseExist` doesn't refer to the path of the files, so it must be seeing something else, but where? Is this a correct method for the user of the program to create, delete, and detect these databases?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//my additions
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataProg15
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static string form1ConnectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; ";
    private string form1DatabasePath = "C:\\DbTemp";

    private void btnCreateDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameToCreate = cbxDb.Text;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(form1ConnectionString);

        string str = "CREATE DATABASE " +nameToCreate+ " ON PRIMARY " +
            "(NAME = " +nameToCreate+ "_Data, " +
            "FILENAME = '" +form1DatabasePath+ "\\" +nameToCreate+ ".mdf', " +
            "SIZE = 4MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
            "LOG ON (NAME = " +nameToCreate+ "_Log, " +
            "FILENAME = '" +form1DatabasePath+ "\\" +nameToCreate+ ".ldf', " +
            "SIZE = 1MB, " +
            "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
            "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" + nameToCreate + "' was created successfully");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in CreateDatabase " + ex.ToString(), "Exception in CreateDatabase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    private void btnDeleteDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameToDelete = cbxDb.Text;
        string myConnectionString = form1ConnectionString + "AttachDBFileName = " + form1DatabasePath + "\\" + nameToDelete + ".mdf ";
        string str = "USE MASTER DROP DATABASE " + nameToDelete;

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
            myConn.Open();

            try
            {
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" + nameToDelete + "' was deleted successfully");

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception in DeleteDatabase '" +nameToDelete+ "'", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    myConn.Close();
                }
            }
    }

    private void btnDoesDbExist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameToTest = cbxDb.Text;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(form1ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format(
                   "SELECT db_id('" +nameToTest+ "')", nameToTest), connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                if ((command.ExecuteScalar() != DBNull.Value))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" +nameToTest+ "' exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database '" +nameToTest+ "' does not exist");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Thank you to all for replies, and your trouble is greatly appreciated.

I now understand that I'm using the wrong database so I've tried to use `SQL Server Compact` instead. Have uninstalled, downloaded again, and reinstalled `SQL Server Compact` including `SP1`. Have also downloaded and installed `SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox` from `https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1` . But  Visual Studio has throughout shown an error when I type `using System.Data.SqlServerCe` . Also when I type `SqlCeEngine` or `SqlCecommand`, I assume for the same reason.

In Visual Studio, `SQL Server Data Tools` and `SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox` are shown as installed products, but not `SQL Server Compact`. Do I need to install this into Visual Studio, and if so how is it done?

Comment: You shouldn't interact with the data files. If you really want to do things like this, you have to use 'detach' and 'attach'. At this point, your localdb sqlserver is aware of the database, but can't find the data files.

Comment: This may be overkill in your scenario, but have you considered using [Code-First Entity Framework Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx)?

Comment: Sql Server is a complex system. When you create a database you don't add just a couple of file names but also a lot of system and configuration informations. These info are stored in internal databases  (model, master, temp etc...). Using the Windows Explorer to remove these files Leaves your Sql Server installation in an unstable state because the internal informations are all still there but the files. If you need this kind of freedom choose a different database system (a file based one) like SQLite, Sql Server Compact, even MS-Access.

Comment: I'm mostly surprised you manage to delete the files if the database server is up and running. SQL Server normally tends to lock those files to prevent live databases from bieng deleted.

Comment: @steve - Temp and model would not contain info on a new database. Model is basically nothing more than a "template" for creating new databases. I.e., if you need a specific object to exist in all databases you create, add it in model. Temp would only be used in case you're issuing queries against a database, and somehow parts of the operations would require stuff to happen in the tempdb.

Comment: @SchmitzIT right on both comments. I was just enforcing the idea....

Comment: Thank you for replies. I'm trying to use `SQL Server Compact` instead but having difficulty as explained in the edit above.

Answer (score 2):

In `Solution Explorer` under `References`, check that `System.Data.SqlServerCe` is listed. If not, right click on `References` then `Add Reference` -> `Browse` button and select the file `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`, probably in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop`. `System.Data.SqlServerCe` should now appear under `References`.

The program below appears to work, and is much simpler. Thanks to all for assistance.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//my additions
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;

namespace DataProg15
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static string form1DatabasePath = "C:\\DbTemp\\dbtemp1.sdf";
        public static string form1ConnectionString = "Data Source = " +form1DatabasePath;

        private void btnCreateDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(form1ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                engine.CreateDatabase();
                MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" +form1DatabasePath+ "' was created successfully");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception in CreateDatabase " + ex.ToString(), "Exception in CreateDatabase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            finally
            {
                engine.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void btnDeleteDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(form1DatabasePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(form1DatabasePath);
                    MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" +form1DatabasePath+ "' was deleted successfully");
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception in DeleteDatabase '" +form1DatabasePath+ "'", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnDoesDbExist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(form1DatabasePath))
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" +form1DatabasePath+ "' exists");
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("DataBase '" +form1DatabasePath+ "' does not exist");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will not let you delete the physical files of a database if that database is active - EVER. The only you would ever be able to do this is if the database is DETACHED ( as mentioned earlier )

So I suspect something your telling us isn't quite right ??

I would change your "check database exists" logic to be;

> select * from sys.databases where name = 'yourdatabasename'

I would run this query anyway when you have deleted your database, just to see what it returns.

Comment: Thank you. Replies and further reading suggests I should be using a database that exists in the local file only, so I'm trying to use `SQL Server Compact` instead, but still having difficulty as explained in the edit above.